# Qt mouseReleaseEvent with several QLabel -> which label is clicked?

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qlabel

I'm doing an interface with Qt5.5.

I have several Qlabel on a first UI and I have implemented mouseReleaseEvent to open a new UI when I click on the labels.
This works. When I click on the labels, it do "emit clicked" and then the signal "clicked()" calls the slot "slotClicked()" and it open the new window.

My problem is: **How can I know which label is clicked?**

Because the window I want to open depends on which label is clicked.

Comment: Are all the labels connected to the same slot?

Comment: yes. I create a class "myLabel" who inherit from QLabel. So then I do `label1 = new myLabel();` and all my labels have the same signal/slot.

Comment: In the class myLabel, I have the function 
`void myLabel::mouseReleaseEvent (QMouseEvent * Event) { emit clicked(); } `

We could may be write a condition `if(label1..)` in this fonction?

Comment: I did not understand the QSignalMapper as in the question "Passing an argument to a slot" so I did differently : in the constructor of my labels, I create a variable "idLabel". When I create a new label, I change his idLabel and then use this one like this `if(idLabel == "...") { ... }.

It works with 2 labels, I will see with more label..